# What is the expression for the confidence interval in a Kaplan-Meier curve?

Tags: r, survival

In R, the survival fit object gives the non-parametric MLE for the survival curve via the Kaplan-Meier estimator. The fit also provides a confidence interval. What is the expression for the confidence interval, or where is the reference, to reproduce the method?

[image]

```
leukemia.surv <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = aml, subset=x=='Nonmaintained') 
plot(leukemia.surv)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default starts with the Nelson-Aalen cumulative hazard estimate $\hat\Lambda(t)$, taking the square root of its variance estimate to get a standard error. If $\Delta \bar N(t_i)$ is the number of events at time $t_i$ and $\bar Y(t_i)$ the number then at risk, the variance estimate is:

$$\text{var}\left[ \hat\Lambda(t) \right] = \sum_{i:t_i \le t} \frac{\Delta \bar N(t_i)}{\bar Y^2(t_i)}.$$

That's Equation 2.4 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842), as recommended by Gavin Simpson; see the corresponding [C code](https://github.com/therneau/survival/blob/master/src/survfitkm.c), at about line 200 in its current incarnation.

That standard error is then transformed to confidence intervals as specified by a `conf.type` argument, with "log" as the default. That default "calculates intervals based on the cumulative hazard or log(survival)," according to the manual page. Code in R implementing the `conf.type` options for a given standard error is visible in `survival:::survfit_confint`.

Comment: [Permalink to line 200](https://github.com/therneau/survival/blob/f2567b77252ac7935eba0ead364665c654ef28d3/src/survfitkm.c#L200) for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

The *survival* package is support software for

Terry M. Therneau, Patricia M. Grambsch (2000). Modeling Survival Data: Extending the Cox Model. Springer, New York. ISBN 0-387-98784-3.

And I suspect that would be the best place to start with the detail of what is implemented in these functions. There are more conceptual details in `?survfit.formula` including what method is used bye default (`"log"` which bases the CI on the log(survival)).

As it happens I saw this [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/lxoWsVco_iM) the other day that covers some of the details of how these confidence intervals are computed.